# Sublime text 3 - Sublime linter - jshint: how to warn about unused 'define' packages?

Tags: javascript, jshint

I'm using a combination of Sublime text 3, Sublime linter and jshint. My project uses AMD, so a js file looks like this:

```
define("path/to/Me", [
  "path/to/pkg1",
  "path/to/pkg2",
], function(
  pkg1,
  pkg2,
){
 var something = new pkg2();
 ...
});
```

Question is, is it possible for the IDE to tell me that 'pkg1 is imported but not used'? The solution doesn't have to be using jshint.